# Uploadin files with too long name

Tags: php, yii2, xampp

I use xampp and yii2 framework To build the app, when i upload a image file with a long name I get this error:

> GET http://backend.dev/upload/Beautiful%20Mix%20HD%20Wallpaper%20 404 (Not Found)

The file name is: `Beautiful Mix HD Wallpaper #20 - p30download.com - 087.jpg`,
The file will be uploaded but when displaying this error occurs.

In php.ini, these settings are correct:
`upload_max_filesize=8M` and `post_max_size=8M`
While the size of my upload files does not go up to this value.

Please tell me where the problem is? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the length of the name.

The filename includes a `#` character which you are putting in the URL without percent escaping it.

A `#` indicates the start of a *fragment identifier*, which is a part of the URL that is handled purely client side and which the browser will not send to the server.

Using a function like [`urlencode`](http://php.net/urlencode) will help you percent escape content in URLs.

Comment: Thank you Quentin, this one was another of my carelessness!